# ITextSharp Multiple Page PDF from several templates

Tags: c#, itext

I have a requirement to generate a PDF from multiple different (Unknown page Sized PDF's)

1. Create a cover sheet from a template and write the text onto it.
2. Pull a PDF (Unknown page size) and append to the above 3) Repeat
3. until all required PDF's are attached

Step 1 is not a problem and this is working, so I have a a cover sheet PDF generated. I now need a way to append the additional PDF's as above. How can we achieve this using ITextSharp?

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to concatenate multiple PDF files into one you may take a look at the [following post](http://geekswithblogs.net/bsherwin/archive/2007/06/29/113566.aspx).

Comment: thanks, I managed to find something called PDFCopy - See above, very simple solution.

Answer (score 2):

I found a simple way to do this, I found something called PDFCopy in ITextSharp

```
void MergePdfStreams(List<Stream> Source, Stream Dest)
        {
            var copy = new PdfCopyFields(Dest);

            foreach (Stream source in Source)
            {
                var reader = new PdfReader(source);
                copy.AddDocument(reader);
            }

            copy.Close();
        }
```

Source : [Is there a straight forward way to append one PDF doc to another using iTextSharp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566899/is-there-a-straight-forward-way-to-append-one-pdf-doc-to-another-using-itextshar)